# Android MenuAction Button has wrong aspect ratio

Tags: android, android-menu

The **action button on the menu has wrong aspect ratio.** While it is not an image view, **I cannot set scaleType or anything on it.**

It was working for years, **now that Android 8 came out** and I have increased the targed and build SDK version it is shows like this.

**"ic_gps_fixed_white_48dp"** is a drawable, actual PNGs, for all screen densities (hdpi, xhdpi and so on...)

Any ideas?

menu xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context="com.example.toolbar.MainActivity">


    <item
        android:id="@+id/my_location_menu_btn"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_gps_fixed_white_48dp"
        android:title=""
        app:showAsAction="always" />


</menu>
```

[image]

Comment: and where is source of ic_gps_fixed_white_48dp ... **also size of actionbar icon should be 24dp**

Comment: @Selvin see my edit, please

Comment: *"ic_gps_fixed_white_48dp" is a drawable, actual PNGs* Why didn't you use VectorDrawable?

Comment: @Selvin I have made this project 4 years ago. Should I switch all drawables that I can to VectorDrawables?

Comment: I will do this ... fx as I wrote the size should be 24 not 48 ... it is pain in the ass to resize multiple pngs(for all dpis) ... with VectorDrawble you have only one file for every dpi and "resize" is as easy as changing 2 value in this file (+ eventually rename file - so it will not have misleading size in the name)

Comment: @Selvin Well I know the pros, just didn't know it can cause aspect ratio issues. But I have changed to vector drawable and it is working now fine. Please add this as an answer so I can accept it.